# O HTTP/2 precisa de algo além da configuração no servidor para funcionar?

Tags: apache, http, http2

Já tenho o HTTP/2 configurado no servidor, testando pelo https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test o resultado é:

> HTTP/2 protocol is supported.
>
> ALPN extension is supported.

Mas olhando pelo log de acesso vejo que todos os acessos continuam sendo pelo HTTP/1.1, nenhum pelo HTTP/2.

Tem algo que preciso fazer para os usuários começarem a acessar por HTTP/2, talvez mudar um `header` ou algo assim? Ou ainda depende de futuras atualizações dos navegadores para começar a valer? Btw, o servidor é apache, e a aplicação no server é em PHP.

Comment: Não adianta o servidor ter suporte e o cliente não. Os logs que analisou foi de requisições feitas por um cliente que suporta o HTTP2?

Comment: @Costamilam Não sei dizer. Na verdade a pergunta é justamente essa. Estando habilitado no servidor, depende apenas de um comportamento do navegador (que pelo jeito ainda não é padrão), ou eu posso setar algo que force o navegador a usar o HTTP/2? Tem algum `header`, ou `meta` que eu precise adicionar ainda no PHP ou HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação do Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html#push), você pode controlar as requisições *PUSH* através do cabeçalho de resposta `Link`. Isto é, se irá responder seu cliente com um arquivo HTML que depende de um arquivo CSS e outro JS, você pode enviá-los ao cliente através de *PUSH* antes que o mesmo necessite requisitá-los.

Você pode fazer isso diretamente na configuração do seu servidor, para cada rota

```
<Location /xxx.html>
    Header add Link "</xxx.css>;rel=preload"
    Header add Link "</xxx.js>;rel=preload"
</Location>
```

Ou simplesmente adicionar os cabeçalhos na resposta. Com PHP você é capaz disso através da função `header`:

```php
<?php

header("Link </xxx.css>;rel=preload, </xxx.js>; rel=preload");
```

Assim, quando o cliente carregar sua página HTML já receberá também os arquivos CSS e JS.

Para o primeiro acesso, que cria a conexão com o servidor, basta informar a versão do HTTP durante a requisição:

```
GET / HTTP/2
Host: localhost
```

O navegador, possuindo suporte para o HTTP/2, já fará isso por conta. Você pode verificar isso nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor no seu navegador. Aqui, acessando uma página em um servidor com suporte ao HTTP/2, que envia via PUSH o arquivo CSS, ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor `h1` em `Protocol` indica HTTP/2 e para o arquivo CSS, segundo da lista, é possível ver `Push` como `Iniciator` da requisição.

Comment: Então apenas se eu utilizar o preload é que  vai acessar por http/2?

Comment: @gustavox O cabeçalho HTTP...

Comment: O cabeçalho `Link`? Mas se for isso então se eu não usar preload, e digamos que não queira carregar nada antes, então mesmo estando habilitado o http2 não será usado pra nada? Ou tem um cabeçalho próprio que indica pra usar sempre que for possível o http2., mesmo sem usar push?

Comment: @gustavox Eu não entendi o seu comentário.  Como assim "carregar nada antes"?

Comment: Então, eu não entendi ainda quando é usado o http/2. O `push` pelo que entendi é utilizado quando quero carregar os dados de uma próxima página que acredito que será requisitada certo? Por ex. tenho um form que o resultado abre em outra pag..  continua

Comment: Então com o `header Link` já posso ir baixando o CSS e JS da próxima página... Mas e se eu não tiver interesse nisso p. ex.? O acesso sem usar isso será por http/1.1. É o uso do Link header que faz usar o http/2?

Comment: Anderson, depende apenas do navegador ter suporte após ter configurado no servidor? Pq o http2 não é só o push, certo? Sua resposta está legal, mas não foi o que perguntei e continuo na dúvida, já que mesmo tendo suporte nenhum acesso ocorre em http2. São poucas versões de navegador que acessam por http/2? Poderia por favor complementar ainda que seja algo básico como "Não precisa fazer nada, depende do navegador"? Valeu

Comment: @gustavox Acho que entendi. Nesse caso você pode fazer a requisição passando a versão HTTP/2 mesmo, por exemplo `GET / HTTP/2`. Verei se acho alguma informação de como o navegador lida com isso

Comment: Cara, então, foi mal, eu não passei uma info importante na pergunta (pq achei irrelevante), e isso que causou a dificuldade pra quem tentou responder. É que como quem provê o http2 é a cloudflare, no log de acesso não aparece o acesso http2 por causa disso: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/214534978-Are-the-HTTP-2-or-SPDY-protocols-supported-between-CloudFlare-and-the-origin-server- [continua]

Comment: Então testei pelo inspetor com a ajuda desta pergunta providencial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213421/how-can-i-view-the-protocol-used-in-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab e vi que as conexões já estão sendo em http2. Por isso acho que tanto você quanto a outra resposta focaram naquilo que é possível manipular no nível da aplicação (o server push). Na verdade acho que na sua resposta só falta dizer que depois de configurado corretamente no servidor, não é preciso fazer nada. No meu caso bastou clicar num botão. :)

Comment: Quer dizer, pra usar o server push precisa, mas para os outros recursos (multiplexação, headers binários etc) é só configurar no servidor que o cabeçalho h2 já é enviado, então a nível da aplicação não precisa fazer nada a não ser que queira usar o server push...

Comment: É isso né? haha

Comment: @gustavox Sim, tudo indica que sim. Pelo o que li, o navegador (atualmente) já irá verificar se o servidor permite o uso de HTTP/2 e utilizará, mas estou procurando uma informação oficial sobre isso.

Comment: Sim, mas só alguns navegadores não suportam, poucos, e se não tiver cai automático no HTTP 1.1. Estando configurado no servidor e enviando o header h2 https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#versioning, ele já faz a conexão em http/2. É mágico. :)

Comment: Os browser que já suportam: https://caniuse.com/#feat=http2

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, pode ser que seja o navegador dos clientes que não suportam o HTTP/2 e seus recursos. Por exemplo, às vezes o navegador não suporta o server push e o ignora (como é o caso do Safari 9.0).

Todavia, existe a configuração por parte do servidor, na aplicação em si, que no caso você tem que verificar se fosse fez.
Você deve incluir nas response um cabeçalho Link que lista as URLs dos recursos adicionais que serão alvo do server push, para envio de uma vez só ao cliente. Então o servidor, caso suporte HTTP/2 e esteja configurado (como me parece no seu caso), lê esse header e faz as devidas ações para transformar num server push.

E, conforme explicado no artigo do link a seguir, os servidores necessitam de alguma forma receber dos desenvolvedores, ou seja, serem informado, de quais recursos devem ser alvo do server push. Ainda não existe uma regra, mas parece haver um consenso se formando em torno de usar a RFC de Web Linking para essa comunicação. É assim que o Apache faz e é assim que o Google App Engine faz.

A sintaxe da RFC de Web Linking manda a gente colocar a URL do recurso, o tipo dele e a relação que temos com ele. No caso, para o server push funcionar, queremos uma relação de preload.

Da uma linda nesse artigo: https://blog.caelum.com.br/http2-server-push-na-pratica/

Comment: Então, como disse na outra resposta, eu não passei uma info importante na pergunta (pq achei irrelevante), e isso que causou a dificuldade pra quem tentou responder. É que como quem provê o http2 é a cloudflare, no log de acesso não aparece o acesso http2 por que a cloudflare não usa entre ela e o servidor de origem. Mas valeu pela resposta. +1